# Show that $\alpha(G) < \beta(G)$ in homogeneous graph

Tags: graph-theory

Problem is:

> If $G$ graph is homogeneous, then $\alpha(G) \le{|V(G)| \over 2}$

By the Gallais theorem, for any $G$ graph $\alpha(G) + \beta(G) = |V|$, so from that it is enough to show that $$\alpha(G) \le \beta(G)$$After what I don't know where to go.

Any help or hint is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I recall that $\alpha(G)$ is the independence number, but forgot what $\beta$ is

Comment: Measures the level of connectivity in a graph and is expressed by the relationship between the number of links (e) over the number of nodes (v).

In other words $\beta = {e \over v}$

Comment: Isn't the edgeless graph $G=nK_1$ on $n$ vertices homogeneous with $\alpha(G)=n$?

Comment: Yes You are right sir